Is doing bug bounty on coinbase or binance halal or haram? And doing on banks who usually earn money from interest?
Coinbase and binance have some issues. But as per their bounty programes, it is nessary to keep the money of it's user safe. So if I help them by doing bug bounty, will i be part of their non-permissible things. And get punished. or not?
